# BigQuery Authorized Views from Apache Beam

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to query a view in BigQuery using Apache Beam.

The view has access to all of the datasets that it references. The Dataflow/GCE service account has access to the view, but **not to its underlying datasets** (this should not be a problem).

When I try to run a job that queries the Authorized View, I get an error like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to get table: test_13249, aborting after 9 retries.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl.executeWithRetries(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1004)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.getTable(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:491)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.getTable(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:477)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.getTable(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryQueryHelper.executeQuery(BigQueryQueryHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryQuerySourceDef.getTableReference(BigQueryQuerySourceDef.java:113)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryQuerySource.getTableToExtract(BigQueryQuerySource.java:65)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase.extractFiles(BigQuerySourceBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase.split(BigQuerySourceBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources.splitAndValidate(WorkerCustomSources.java:290)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources.performSplitTyped(WorkerCustomSources.java:212)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources.performSplitWithApiLimit(WorkerCustomSources.java:196)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources.performSplit(WorkerCustomSources.java:175)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSourceOperationExecutor.execute(WorkerCustomSourceOperationExecutor.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:417)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:386)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:140)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:120)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Access Denied: Table my-gcp-project:bigquery_dataset_any.test_13249: User does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table my-gcp-project:bigquery_dataset_any.test_13249.",
    "reason" : "accessDenied"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Denied: Table my-gcp-project:bigquery_dataset_any.test_13249: User does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table my-gcp-project:bigquery_dataset_any.test_13249.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beam tries to be smart when dealing with BigQuery. This error happens because Beam inspects tables referenced by a query, and this is not always possible with Authorized Views.

To work around this issue, you can use the method `withQueryLocation` in `BigQueryIO.readTableRows()` or `BigQueryIO.read(SerializableFunction)`. This will allow Beam to use the provided query location, and not infer one.

Therefore:

```
BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
    .fromQuery("SELECT * FROM my_authorized_view")
    .withQueryLocation("US")  // Whatever location is convenient for you
    ...
```

this should work around your issue.